# How to save number from user input?

Tags: android, user-input

Recently I've started to mess around with Android Studio and decided to make an app. I've made the most of my app, but I encounter a little problem. I need to memorize in a variable a number from user input, but I don't know how to that, I've tried solutions found on the internet, even here but I get an error.
Can somebody help me with some ideas or the code edited which I must put in my app ?
This is the java code for the activity:

```
public class calc_medie_teza extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText adaug_nota;
static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;
TextView afisare;
TextView afisare2;
Button calc;
EditText note_nr;
EditText nota_teza;
int suma;
double medie;
double medieteza;
int nr_note = 0;
int notamedie;
int notateza;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_medie_teza);
    afisare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.afisare);
    afisare2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.afisare2);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(this);
    note_nr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_nr);
    nota_teza = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nota_teza);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calc_medie_teza, menu); // creare meniu
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId(); // meniu
    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onClick(View v) // afisare medie
{
    calcul_medie();
}

public void buton_adauga(View v)
{
    if(note_nr == )
    suma = suma + notamedie;
    nr_note = nr_note + 1;
}
public double calcul_medie() // calculul mediei
{
    medie = suma / nr_note;
    medieteza = ((medie * 3)+ notateza)/4;
    return medieteza;
}
```

Here is a photo with the activity: http://onlypro.ro/img/images/ootllv2f55hnwdgi0xlv.png

Basically the app needs to add the input number to variable when I press the "Adauga nota" [Add grade] button and then I have to insert the "teza" number and when press the "Calculeaza media" [Calculate] the app will then calculate the calcul_medie() and return a decimal number. Between "Introduceti notele aici" [Add grades here] and "Adaugata nota"[Add grade] I have a Number enter text, the same is between "Introduceti teza aici" [Add thesis bere] and "Calculeaza media" [Calculate]. I don't know how to store the number the user puts in and sum it in "notamedie" variable.

I hope you understand my problem.
For any questions you'll have I'll respond as soon as I can.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you need the number from the edittext?

Comment: @kelvincer yes I need the number from the edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think your probably asked how to get the input of the String from the UI and translate them into Integer/BigDecimal. If so, here is some solution:

1. first, you get get the string from the UI:

   > String input = note_nr.getText().toString().trim();
2. change the string input to integer/BigDecimal:

   > int number1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
   >
   > BigDecimal number2 = new BigDecimal(input);

Correct me if misunderstood your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the problem at all. Please clearly define the problem and use english if you can. As fas the I understood there will be a Edittext to which the user will input the value. Gets its value in the activity and then use it.

```
EditText edittext;
editext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editext);
String value = edit text.getText().toString(); // the value that the user inputted in String data format
// Here for addition you will need the value in int or decimal for that
int valueInt = Integer.parse(value); // this will be the value in int type
double valueInt =  = Double.parseDouble(value); // this will be the value (user inputted) in double data type ( which you will need if you want to use decimal numbers).
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've used the declarations in my native language which is romanian.

Answer (score 0):

When you press a button just retrieve the appropriate value from the edittext in the following way

```
edittext = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
String string = edittext.getText().toString();
```

Comment: "Not woking" has a big scope. Can you explain what exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve the text do this

```
String string = note_nr.getText().toString();

// Converting String to int
int myValue =Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that one more time, but the IDE says that the variable I used for "string" is never used, but I've used it.

```
    number1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1); 
    String number_1 = number1.getText().toString(); 
number2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2); 
String number_2= number2.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

R3muSGFX, can you post the whole codes?

String number_1 = number1.getText().toString(); this line codes just mean that you initialized a String variable "number_1".

and you will used it when app perform a math function, like you wrote in the beginning:

> public double calcul_medie()
>       {
>           medie = suma / nr_note;
>           medieteza = ((medie * 3)+ notateza)/4;
>           return medieteza;
>       }

but if you did not use "number_1" at all, IDE will imply you the warning message
:the variable I used for "string" is never used